# Can Annex be used to describe splitting up?

Tags: word-usage

My two kids are arguing at the dinner table. Driving my wife, me, and their grandfather mad. The living room has a 'room' sort of attached to it, but no door, just a window into it. It's accessible via the kitchen. We call it the 'back room' . I say *maybe we should annex them in the back room* and then get crucified by my wife and her dad for improper use of *annex* as it means *to join* and not *to split*. I get that, but I felt/feel that using *annex* in the context I described was OK.

If you have a group of people and within that group there is a smaller group of people you want to separate but keep close, (i.e. two annoying kids), is it fair use of English to say *we should annex them*?

Comment: Your family is right; 'annex' means to attach another group to your own, not separate them. BTW, it's 'driving my wife and _me_ mad'.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that, perhaps unintentionally, you are using *annex* in a neologistic way ("To put in the annex"), in a similar way to saying "Maybe we should back-room them".

**But because *annex* as a verb already has an established meaning, you can't make it mean what you want.** This is especially true when the meaning you intend is entirely opposed to the established meaning.

You need a word which does not have that established meaning — perhaps even "back-room", which is a noun that might stand being verbed.